# Add an output to a non built-in MatLab function

Tags: matlab, struct, output

I have downloaded a non built-in MatLab function, on MatLab file exchange. This function is "struct2table" (for MatLab Version >2013 this function is implemented as a built-in, unfortunately my MatLab version is 2012).
With this function I would like to create an output on my workspace that could be usable afterwards.

Unfortunately the code I have downloaded (on http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/36214-struct2table/content/struct2table.m ), is not able to produce any workspace output. Does anyone as an idea about how to change this function in order to produce an output in the workspace?

Comment: Isnt this something to ask on the file exchange, specifically to the author of this code?

Comment: I fully agree with @A.Visser. Except for that I have some comments. The file does not return anything by design. In case you want the function to return something you need to modify the function. This modification must not violate the terms in the provided BSD license (which allows the user to modify it as the user wants in this case if I understood it correctly). However, I would strongly suggest you read up on [functions](http://se.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/function.html) first to see what possibilities you have.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Modifying Function

To make the function `struct2table` output something you need to change the line

```
function struct2table(varargin)
```

to

```
function [output1, output2, ...] = struct2table(varargin)
```

without the `...`. *They are present just to show you can have multiple outputs.*

The names `output1`, `output2` and so on should be the same as the variables you want to retrieve from the function. For example it could be `formatString` or `fprintfArgs`.

## Calling Function

Then when you call `struct2table` you can retrieve only the first output argument with

```
output1 = struct2table(...)
```

or more of the output arguments with

```
[output1, output2, ...] = struct2table(...)
```